# Create an object when a form loads in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am going to write a project to present an AVL tree like this:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQHgS.png)

I have two classes: AVLTree & TreePresantation.
The problem is I can't use methods of my classes within a Button_Click

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AVLTree avltree = new AVLTree();
        TreePresantation treePresantation = new TreePresantation(avltree);
    }

    private void BtnPut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtPutKey.Text == null) || (txtPutValue.Text == null))
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Key or Value cannot be empty!";
        }
        else
        {
            treepresantation.Put(Convert.ToInt32(txtPutKey.Text), txtPutValue.Text);
        }
    }
```

"treepresantation" in btnPut_Click is red under-lined
and the error is: Error CS0103  The name 'treepresantation' does not exist in the current context

can anyone help me?

Comment: The variable `treePresantation` goes out of [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) at the `}`. Make it a member variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: How should I do that? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: If that's your question, then you need a C# tutorial. I have put a link on the word "scope".

Comment: with every click of a button, I want the same tree to be updated. If I create an AVLTree in the scope of a Button_Click, I won't be able to achieve that.

Comment: @Amineh check answers, scope doesn't limit to methods only, it goes by class, packages, loops etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find a duplicate even if it seems there should be one so here it goes.

Your variables are **not in the same scope** as where you call them so you can't call them.

Here is one way to fix your problem :

```cs
public YourClass {

    private AVLTree avltree;
    private TreePresantation treePresantation;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        avltree = new AVLTree();
        treePresantation = new TreePresantation(avltree);
    }

    private void BtnPut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtPutKey.Text == null) || (txtPutValue.Text == null))
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Key or Value cannot be empty!";
        }
        else
        {
            treepresantation.Put(Convert.ToInt32(txtPutKey.Text), txtPutValue.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

But as Thomas pointed out you should find a C# tutorial to understand the basics.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you don't need to access `avltree` somewhere else than in `Form1_Load` you can remove it from your local class properties.

Comment: Your `this.`usage is not consistent and might confuse OP.

Comment: You are right, I usually use `this` when I instantiate my objects like in ctor but after that I don't use it anymore. Since it is not needed anyway I will remove it from my answer thanks @ThomasWellers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Form1
{
    private TreePresantation treePresantation = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AVLTree avltree = new AVLTree();
        treePresantation = new TreePresantation(avltree);
    }

    private void BtnPut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtPutKey.Text == null) || (txtPutValue.Text == null))
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Key or Value cannot be empty!";
        }
        else
        {
            treepresantation.Put(Convert.ToInt32(txtPutKey.Text), txtPutValue.Text);
        }
    }
}
```